# Turning on Glimpse causes browser to keep reloading

Tags: glimpse

I am trying to manually add glimpse to an existing WebForms site.

I added Glimpse.Core.dll to the bin directory and edited my web.config as described [here](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Setup).

When I go to http://localhost/Glimpse.axd, I see the Glimpse config page and everything seems OK.  When I click "Turn Glimpse On", a banner is added to the top of the page telling me that "Glimpse is now ON".  Everything looks great so far.

When I go back to my site, the page loads, the glimpse icon pops up in the lower right corner, and then the page refreshes.  Then the process starts over again.  If I go back and turn off glimpse, the refresh loop stops.

I've looked at the refresh loop using fiddler, but nothing looks out of place.  I've tried to use Firebug or the Chrome developer tools to see what's going on, but the page refreshes to fast for me to see anything.

I'm using glimpse 0.86 and .NET 4.0 on IIS 7 .5 (Windows 7).

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that you have properly closed any script tags or other markup on your page.

The only time I've seen reports of this behavior was when a page's markup was malformed, and the inclusion of a new/unexpected script caused the page's own javascript to execute.

The Glimpse client, to the best of my knowledge, does not actually have redirect code in it.